# Undefined Index value in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.4 want to send form to database but it shows me this error:

> Undefined index: manager

everything is correct, but I am struggling to figure out why this is not work.

**My Model:**

```
protected $fillable =['name','clinic_id','tel1','tel2','tel3','tel4'
    ,'country','province','city','address','manager','manager_tel','parent_id'];
```

**My controller :**

```
    $data = $request->except('_token');

    //dd($data);
    Clinic::create([
        'manager' => $data['manager'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
//      'clinic_id' => $data['clinic_id'],
        'tel1' => $data['tel1'],
        'tel2' => $data['tel2'],
        'tel3' => $data['tel3'],
        'tel4' => $data['tel4'],
        'country' => $data['country'],
        'province' => $data['province'],
        'city' => $data['city'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'manager_tel' => $data['manager_tel'],
    'clinic_id' => $data['clinicID']
]);

return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => 'ok']);
```

**My View:**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 float-right">
    <label> مدیر کلینیک : </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-right"  name="manager" id="SetClinic1" required disabled>
</div><!-- form-group -->
<div class="form-group col-md-3 float-right">
    <label> شماره تماس مدیر : </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-right"
           placeholder="09125461111" dir="ltr" name="manager_tel" required>
    @if($errors->has('manager_tel'))
        {{$errors->first('manager_tel')}}
    @endif
</div><!-- form-group -->
```

Comment: I'm not much into Laravel, but shouldn't you use `Driver` into your configuration?
possible duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066886/laravel-undefined-index-driver/46067339) link and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228148/laravel-database-connection-returns-undefined-index-error) link. Check them out.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Elements with Disabled attribute are not submitted  . That's why `$data['manager']` is undefined . Remove the disabled attribute from this line like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right"  name="manager" id="SetClinic1" required >
```

And the error will be resolved. Also you can make the field read only instead of disabled.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control text-right"  name="manager" id="SetClinic1" readonly>
```

Comment: actually  i need disabled attribute for the rest of code . and i removed it for a once but still it dosen't working.

Comment: what is output of `dd($data);` after removing disabled attribute

Answer (score 0):

The field named 'manager' is disabled so you can not get `'manager' => $data['manager']` on controller, you can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` so you can get the value on controller.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 float-right">
    <label> مدیر کلینیک : </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-right"  name="manager" id="SetClinic1" required readonly>
</div>
```